# Neural Network Custom Binary Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I am trying to design a neural network that makes a custom binary prediction.

Normally to do binary prediction, I would use a softmax as my last layer, and then my loss could be the difference between the prediction I made and the true binary value.

However, what if I don't want to use a softmax layer. Instead, I output a real valued number, and check if some condition on this number is true. In a really simple case, I check if this number is positive. If it is, I predict `1`, else I predict `0`. Let's say I want all the numbers to be positive, so the true predictions should be all 1, and then I want to train this network such that it outputs all positive numbers. I am confused as how to formulate a loss function for this problem, so that I am able to back propagate and train the network.

Does anyone have an idea how to create this kind of network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused as how to formulate a loss function for this problem, so
>   that I am able to back propagate and train the network.

Here's how you should approach it. Effectively, you need to transform the labels to positive and negative target values (say `+1` and `-1`) and solve the *regression problem*. The loss function can be a simple L1 or L2 loss. The network will try to learn to output a prediction close to the training target, which you can afterwards interpret if it's closer to one target or another, i.e. positive or negative. You can even go ahead and make some targets larger (e.g. `+2` or `+10`) to emphasize that these examples are very important. Example code: [linear regression in tensorflow](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.py).

However, I simply have to warn you that your approach has serious drawbacks, see for instance [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22381/130598). One outlier in training data can easily skew your predictions. Classification with softmax + cross-entropy loss is more stable, that's why almost always a better choice.

Comment: I'm confused at your solution. Having labels as `+1` and `-1` is fine, but how would I have this as a L2 Loss? I manually check the result of my network to see if it is a positive value, so what do you mean by making some targets larger? Maybe the problem is that I am manually checking the result at the end, and there is some better way to do that. Because in this case, where `true_labels` is a tensor of all 1's, and `predicted_labels` is `+1` or `-1` depending on if its pos or not, a L2 loss can be `(true_labels -  predicted_labels)`, but this won't work right because the gradients are 0.

Comment: Also, you say my solution has drawbacks, does that mean it is not possible to train a neural network to just output positive values? It seems like this should be a pretty simple task.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. L2 loss is the usual choice for regression problems. See the example I provided, it uses exactly L2 loss. Have you tried it? Also predicted values won't equal the targets exactly. The question I mention discusses the drawbacks of your approach.

Comment: I am just trying to predict positive numbers, not a certain number. Because of this I look at the result and "predict" 1 if it is positive and -1 if it negative. So why do you say predicted values won't equal the targets exactly? My predicted values are 1 and -1, and my target is 1?

Comment: You are talking about *interpretation*, I'm talking about neural network that solves *regression* problem. Whatever you do with its output has no connection to the NN. In other words, it's not part of backprop.

Comment: Ok, I think I am starting to understand how to do this. I'll let you know if I have any other questions. Thanks for the help!